# How can I find out what email I used to sign up using the Android app?

Tags: support, android-app, user-accounts

EDIT: I tried logging the exact same way, except from Electrical Engineering (the first community I joined), and this time it worked. I though where you tried to log in had no impact on your Stack exchange account, turns out it does. Thanks everyone who answered!

Some time ago I created this very account, using the same phone I am using now. My problem is, I have no idea how I created the account.

I apparently used neither my usual mail address nor my usual Google account. When I log out then back in with this phone, it works using a Google account but I suspect it is my friend's, who logged multiple times on other Google apps on my phone.

This account doesn't have much, and I could easily create another, but I don't like creating multiple accounts just because I lost one. Help?

Comment: I don't get it. When you log out, and then back in, it work? To log back in, you have to choose an account! So which account are you choosing?

Comment: Well, it doesn't ask for an account... it just logs in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being that when you sign in using your Google account, it doesn't ask you to choose between accounts, it must be that you only have one Google account on your phone, and that's the account you are using for SE.

So here's how to find which account it's using: go to your phone settings  → accounts  → Google. There it will say the email address used across all Google products. The same email credentials are used for the SE app.

You can now try signing into your account from a browser using that email address.

If you're having trouble signing in using that account, go to SE's [forgot password page](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery), and enter that email address. They will send you an email where you'll be able to change your password.